# Alamofire JSON Request not pulling the data from a server

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, alamofire

Im using Alamofire to pull a JSON file from a server (http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json). To do this I have an Alamofire Request function which should pull the data down and write it to a class called `JSONDataClass`.

**Alamofire Request**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json")
            .response { request, response, data,  error in

                if let data = data {
                    let json = JSON(data:data)

                    for locationData in json {
                        let locationDataJSON = JSONDataClass(json: locationData.1)
                        self.cacheData.append(locationDataJSON)
                    }

                    for title in self.cacheData {
                        print(title.memoryTitle)
                    }
                }

        }
```

However my printLn isn't printing the data from the JSON File which indicates there is a problem with either the request or the class. However I'm new to swift and can't seem to work out the problem, all help is appreciated!

**Class**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

class JSONDataClass {

    //Location MetaData
    var postUser: String!
    var memoryTitle: String!
    var memoryDescription: String!
    var memoryType: String!
    var memoryEmotion: String!
    var taggedFriends: String!

    //Location LocationalData
    var memoryLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    //MultiMedia AddressData
    var media1: String!
    var media2: String!
    var media3: String!
    var media4: String!
    var media5: String!

    //Writing to varibles
    init(json: JSON) {
        postUser = json["user"].stringValue
        memoryTitle = json["title"].stringValue
        memoryDescription = json["description"].stringValue
        memoryType = json["type"].stringValue
        memoryEmotion = json["emotion"].stringValue
        taggedFriends = json["friends"].stringValue

        memoryLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: json["latitude"].doubleValue, longitude: json["longitude"].doubleValue)

        media1 = json["media1"].stringValue
        media2 = json["media2"].stringValue
        media3 = json["media3"].stringValue
        media4 = json["media4"].stringValue
        media5 = json["media5"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Comment: inside your Alamofire call, just above your if-let data statement. Add print(response) and see what your server response is. This will help signal what the problem is.

Comment: Also, iOS 9 introduced App Transport Security have you disabled that?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Here it the print - Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fbbb834a770> { URL: http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Content-Length" = 4596;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 30 Dec 2015 19:07:26 GMT";
    Etag = "\"11f4-528216d0e395b\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 30 Dec 2015 18:08:32 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)";
} })

Comment: So you have a status code 200 which means you should have data, now print out your data object in the same spot. print(data) - If you see several blocks of digits, then you've got your data.

Comment: Im getting a lot of optional numbers which I assume is the data

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Im not to sure what that means sorry, new to all of this

Comment: after i check the discussion and the data provided by the server from you link, i can say, that your trouble is how to deal with your JSON (class, or struct, or enum??) Did you follow some tutorial from SwiftyJSON? While your init(json: JSON) in class JSONDataClass seems to accept some JSON object ( aka dictionary), in reality your json is an JSON array! Check SwiftyJSON documentation and take in your account, that you received an array.

Comment: ... try for d in json {
                        let locationDataJSON = JSONDataClass(json: d)
                        self.cacheData.append(locationDataJSON)
                    } and see, that locationDataJSON is NOT location data but one json object from the received array. or just remove .1 in locationData.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: the author of the JSON content has fixed his JSON based on my answer  - my answer was correct at the time of this post).

---

The problem is that you've got invalid JSON coming back from the server.

I switched your SwiftyJSON code out and wrapped it in a try-catch which illuminated the problem:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json")
            .response { request, response, data,  error in
                //print("status \(response)")

            do {

                let myData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                    options: .MutableLeaves)

                print(myData)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

And I get the following error:

> 2015-12-30 13:47:06.129 {{ignore}}[10185:2174510] Unknown class log in Interface Builder file.
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 961."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around
>   character 961.}

This error basically means that you have invalid JSON coming back from the server.

Make sure your json is valid by running it through JSONLint:

### http://jsonlint.com

Comment: It's saying, 'status FAILURE', however I've copy and pasting the code above am I meant to add anything when you said 'print out your values'?

Comment: @MattHammond update, here's what you should check next

Comment: I get null in the log

Comment: @MattHammond updated, I'll probably move on after this, but hopefully you get the picture as to how you can debug using print statements

Comment: Yes is this really interesting to see how print's can let you know why its broken, however I still getting null

Comment: Im in your chat the by way

Comment: It's pretty helpful but @Joshua Nozzi is correct, nothing helps you with troubleshooting like learning how to debug properly. Spend 1 day watching wwdc videos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99336/discussion-between-matt-hammond-and-dan-beaulieu).

Comment: check just the link  http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json  in your browser. it is nothing wrong there ...

Comment: That's because the author of the context fixed the issue based on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you new to debuggers and breakpoints?

Set a breakpoint in your response closure (for example, in your `if let data = data {` line) and step through your code to see if it does what you expect at every stage. Maybe `error` is set? Maybe the `if let data = data {` conditional failed (you're not doing anything in an `else` to log the failure, so how could you know?)...

Comment: Sorry, Im new to swift and Xcode, what do you mean?

Comment: You'll need to read the Xcode documentation regarding the use of breakpoints and debuggers. A breakpoint pauses the execution of the program wherever you set it (the blue markers that appear when you click in the left gutter of your code) and shows the debugger paused at that line so you can step through and examine the state of your code at runtime. This isn't specific to Swift / Xcode. This is *very basic programming knowledge* that you *cannot* be successful without understanding.

Comment: Here's a video from Apple on debugging with Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-412/

Comment: Yes I'm new to swift breakpoints, have only really been learning swift on and off for a few weeks max, didn't think I was doing anything complex enough to really utilise the breakpoints and debuggers

Comment: Any time something goes wrong, the debugger is your friend. It's *the* go-to tool. I spend almost as much time in it as I do writing code. (That's normal.) Do yourself a **HUGE** favor and make learning the breakpoint and debugger basics your top priority. You'll be *so* glad you did. It's really not that difficult and the returns far outweigh the time spent learning it.

Comment: I shall do, I have added an else at the end of the IF and the print that I set in the else isn't being printed so data must contain data

Comment: Then I'd examine the `error` variable when paused inside that closure to see if it's set to anything but `nil`. I'd also make sure your `json` constant (defined in the `let json =...` line) is set to anything but `nil` (after you step past that line to execute it). If you don't get a JSON object, your `for` loops won't be executed since there's nothing to do, so you won't see any printed lines.

Comment: @after this nightmare I shall defiantly spend time learning about debugging for sure, cause this is annoying not know how to fix it and resorting to other people.

Answer (score 2):

After I checked the discussion and the data provided by the server from you link, I can say, that your trouble is how to deal with your JSON (class, or struct, or enum??)

Did you follow some tutorial from SwiftyJSON? While your init(json: JSON) in class JSONDataClass seems to accept some JSON object (aka dictionary), in reality your json is an JSON array! Check SwiftyJSON documentation and take in your account, that you received an array.

try this instead:

```
for d in json { 
    let locationDataJSON = JSONDataClass(json: d)  
    self.cacheData.append(locationDataJSON) 
}
```

and see, that locationDataJSON is NOT location data but one json object from the received array. or just remove .1 in locationData.1

**For example:**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://midlandgates.co.uk/JSON/reliveCacheData.json")
    .response { request, response, data,  error in

        if let data = data {
            let json = JSON(data:data)

            for locationData in json {
                let locationDataJSON = JSONDataClass(json: locationData)
                self.cacheData.append(locationDataJSON)
            }

            for title in self.cacheData {
                print(title.memoryTitle)
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: you might want to add some sort of an explanation as to what you've changed and how this resolves the issue. We've already concluded that the JSON on the server was invalid.

Comment: The author fixed his JSON based on my answer

Comment: @DanBeaulieu i don't see nothing wrong in your answer and generally i think, that we all are trying to help each other.

Comment: I've moved your comments to your question. This improves the overall quality of your post making it a better candidate for upvoting.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu thanks! I don't have any knowledge about SwiftyJSON, I use my own JSON parser / serializer but I am pretty sure that the result of JSON() is not a tuple and that JSONDataClass accept json object as parameter of its init. So I hope, it can help the guy to continue with his project.

Comment: @user3441734 Removing the .1 creates an error: Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') to expected argument type 'JSON'